# How to search string in html with regex expression and highlight with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, regex

Suppose I have a paragraph in which I have to find two keywords like 'chemist's shop' and shop.

```
<div id="content"> <p>I have a shop which is known as chemist's shop and I need some medicine for my shop.</p> </div>
```

In the above paragraph 
**Chemist's shop** will be replaced with **pharmacy**
and **shop** will be replaced with **store**

Below is my code.

```
var list= ["chemist's shop","shop"];
var text= $('#content').html();
var i, len = list.length, reg;
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
     reg = new RegExp("\\b" + list[i] + "\\b", 'gi');
     if (reg.test(text)) {
       text = text.replace(reg, "<a href='#' style='color:red'>"+list[i]+"</a>");
   }
  }
}
```

I want result as

```
<div id="content"><p>I have a <a href='#' style='color:red'>store</a> which is known as <a href='#' style='color:red'>pharmacy</a> and I need some medicine for my <a href='#' style='color:red'>store</a>.</p></div>
```

When I run the code firstly chemist's shop was identified then its shop part was replaced by store.

I have tried to get the output but failed to get the actual result. 
Please help me for my issue. It'll be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `text` should contain the updated string. You're not updating it in DOM.

Comment: Ok, now replace the text `list[i]` with the new text `new_value[i]`, for example.

Comment: I have updated the  code for more clarification

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a new array with the contents you want to update and then in your `text.replace` use the new array's items. 
Finally you have to add them to your `div#content` with the jQuery method `.html()`

I have updated your code. Check the working snippet.

```js
var list= ["chemist's shop","shop"];
var list2 = ["pharmacy", "store"];
var text= $('#content').html();
var i, len = list.length, reg;
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
     reg = new RegExp("\\b" + list[i] + "\\b", 'gi');
     if (reg.test(text)) {
       text = text.replace(reg, "<a href='#' style='color:red'>"+list2[i]+"</a>");
   }
   $('#content').html(text);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"> <p>I have a shop which is known as chemist's shop and I need some medicine for my shop.</p> </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay but the above code is not fitted good when I made changes in array list as below
var list= ["shop", "chemist's shop",];
var list2 = ["store","pharmacy"];
In this unable to search "chemist's shop".

Comment: In this in your first iteration the regex is first matching `shop` in your text and since `shop` is also present in `chemist's shop` it is changing that to store. You need to change your regex to not match the shop in `chemist's shop`

Comment: Yes I need to change the regex exp. But I am not getting any idea to what to change in regexp. Let me know if you have the solution or suggest any other solution. @DragonBorn

Comment: Hello guys! I need resolution to my problem. Please help me out. Thanks